# Android,I need the code that delete all the event of my calendar in my device

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to delete all my event in the calendar,I Have a trying this code:

The actual function that should delete:

```
 private void deleteEvent(ContentResolver resolver, Uri eventsUri, int calendarId) {
    Cursor cursor;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 7) { //up-to Android 2.1 
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" }, "Calendars._id=" + calendarId, null, null);
    } else { //8 is Android 2.2 (Froyo) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)
        cursor = resolver.query(eventsUri, new String[]{ "_id" }, "calendar_id=" + calendarId, null, null);
    }
    while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
        long eventId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("test"));
        resolver.delete(ContentUris.withAppendedId(eventsUri, eventId), null, null);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

And that is the code that calling the delete function:

```
        Uri eventsUri;
    int calendarId=1;
    int osVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (osVersion <= 7) { //up-to Android 2.1 
        eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    } else { //8 is Android 2.2 (Froyo) (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)
        eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    }
    ContentResolver resolver = this.getContentResolver();
    deleteEvent(resolver, eventsUri, calendarId);
```

I try this code on my Htc Desire but no success i will appreciat Help

the log error:

```
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/ActivityThread(1958): Failed to find provider info for calendar
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://calendar/events
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.content.ContentResolver.delete(ContentResolver.java:671)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.DeleteAllContact.Dan.DeleteAllContact.deleteEvent(DeleteAllContact.java:102)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.DeleteAllContact.Dan.DeleteAllContact.access$1(DeleteAllContact.java:100)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.DeleteAllContact.Dan.DeleteAllContact$2.onClick(DeleteAllContact.java:55)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-07 18:07:01.305: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1958):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thank in advence!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
read calendar database

Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),    null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

// fetching calendars id
if(cursor.getcount>0)
{
CId = new int[cursor.getCount()];
int i=0;
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
     CId[i] = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
     i++;
     cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

delete a calender event

```
for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++)
{
Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CALENDAR_URI,Cid[i]);
getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
}
}
```

Comment: When i u this code i have this error: ERROR/ActivityThread(1958): Failed to find provider info for calendar

Comment: @dijo do u know id of the event

Comment: @dijo u can't delete the entire events.u have to delete one by one.first u take eventid from the caleder database and then delete one by one.

Comment: the result that i need is that my calendar will be empty so if the way is to read the database a delete one after one the so YES i want please...

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CALENDAR" />

Comment: try above code i am also use this to code to delete a event??i think there is no user permissions like this android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CALENDAR" />

Comment: I am getting this error :ERROR/DatabaseUtils(317): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: calendar_id: , while compiling: SELECT calendar_id, displayname FROM Calendars WHERE (1)

Comment: do u use smartphone for checking purpose

Comment: @dijo change the diplayname as the tittle nad aslo change calenadar_id to _id

Comment: i have done that still the same error can you add the full code maybe that will be easy

Comment: change the diplayname as the tittle nad aslo change calenadar_id to _id

Comment: Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null,"Allday"+"!="+1+" AND transparency"+"="+0, null, null);    
   if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
     mArray.add(count,cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title")));
     mId.add(count,cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
     count++;
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());

   }

Comment: while(mDeactlist.size()>tem)
     {
      if(mCheck1[tem]!=false)
      {
       mPosition=mArray.indexOf(mtemp1[tem]);
       Editor medit=getSharedPreferences("Activate", 0).edit();
       image.remove(mPosition);
       image.add(mPosition,0);
       medit.putInt(mArray.get(mPosition), 0);medit.commit();
       medit.putInt("count", mActcount-1);medit.commit();
       mActcount--;
       deactivate();
      }
      tem++;
     }

Comment: Can you please explain? i don't understand what you have done (Really a big thank you for your time and help i appreciate)

Comment: i am finally modify the code as in my program try it??if it's not problem in ur device

Comment: try it now ?? it will help u?

Comment: I got that: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(10192): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URL content://calendar/events/1

Comment: use the query like this  getContentResolver().query(uri, null,"Allday"+"!="+1+" AND transparency"+"="+0, null, null);

Comment: I change this line:Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");  To: Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"); so now no error but nothing happen in the calendar

Comment: i try the query but i have this error:android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Allday: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Calendars WHERE (1) AND (Allday!=1 AND transparency=0)

Comment: i think try some other devices??\

Comment: I tried on few device and it dose not working. this line is not right:Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"); it should be like:Uri CALENDAR_URI =Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");

Comment: hi use uri=Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"); below 2.1 devices

Comment: Uri CALENDAR_URI =Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");use this above 2.1