# Android Calendar manipulation question

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api

how to delete all event in code of my calendar everything i try dose not work for me.

So i will appreciate if someone can give me a complete solution on How to Delete all my event from my calendar

Thanks for Helping!!!!

Comment: Belongs on http://android.stackexchange.com/. Also, just delete your calendars (I think you can only do it from the web).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android,I need the code that delete all the event of my calendar in my device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6381561/android-i-need-the-code-that-delete-all-the-event-of-my-calendar-in-my-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can't delete a all events at a time.u can delete one by one.
first u retrieve the event id

```
Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(""content://calendar/events"),    null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

// fetching calendars id
if(cursor.getcount>0)
{
CId = new int[cursor.getCount()];
int i=0;  
while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
{
 CId[i] = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
 i++;
 cursor.moveToNext();
}
```

delete a calender event

`for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++)`
    `{`
    `Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");`
    `Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CALENDAR_URI,Cid[i]);`
    `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);`
    `}`

Comment: Error: ERROR/ActivityThread(25065): Failed to find provider info for calendar

Comment: it is working i had to change this line:"content://calendar/events" to:"content://com.android.calendar/events" Thank you very much!!!!!! big help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Settings->Applications->Manage Applications>Calendar->Clear Data

If not try to find "Calendar Storage" app in the list right below the "Calendar" entry and clear it's data.

Comment: If the calendar is synced with Google Calendar that will not work.